# How to listen to "Backend" value change in tauri-leptos app?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, tauri, leptos

I have tauri command on backend(tauri) that returns a string(light theme value from windows registry). I need to get it on frontend + listen if this string changes. I couldn't find needed functions in leptos or tauri docs.
So I came up with this crutch on frontend:

```rust
let (is_light_theme, set_is_light_theme) = create_signal(String::new());

let is_light_theme_fn = move || {
        spawn_local(async move {
            let is_light_theme_fetch = invoke("is_light_theme", to_value("").unwrap())
                .await
                .as_string()
                .unwrap();
            set_is_light_theme.set(_is_light_theme_);
            loop {
                let old_value = is_light_theme.get();
                let new_value = invoke("is_light_theme", to_value("").unwrap())
                    .await
                    .as_string()
                    .unwrap();
                if new_value != old_value {
                    set_is_light_theme.set(new_value);
                };
                // sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000)).await; // breaks loop
            }
        });
    };
    is_light_theme_fn();
```

tauri command on the backend:

```rust
#[tauri::command]
fn is_light_theme() -> String {
    let theme = helpers::is_light_theme();
    format!("{}", theme)
}
```

`is_light_theme` in helpers:

```rust
pub fn is_light_theme() -> bool {
    let val = CURRENT_USER
        .open(r#"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"#)
        .expect("Failed to get registry key")
        .get_u32("AppsUseLightTheme")
        .expect("Failed to get registry value");
    println!("{}", val);
    val != 0
}
```

This runs somewhat okay but this loop is very process-intensive.
I tried adding sleep from std:thread and tokio to loop, both of them are breaking it.

Maybe there's a better a way to listen for value changes in backend?

Comment: It's a common mistake for Rust to try to sleep inside an async function.
Read more about how async works in Rust, here's a good starting point: https://github.com/rust-lang/async-book/issues/64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backend -> Frontend

You can use Tauri [events](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/events/):

```rust
// in your setup routine or tauri command function, where you can have access to the app handle
app.emit_all("event-name", Payload { message: "Tauri is awesome!".into() }).unwrap();
```

And then listen to this event in the frontend:

```js
import { emit, listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event'

const unlisten = await listen('event-name', (event) => {
  // event.payload is the payload object
  console.log(event);
})
```

========== OLD ANSWER =============

Frontend -> Backend

It's usually a bad idea to continuously poll data, I might be not fully understanding your use case, but here's how I would do it, if I needed to get theme from the frontend.

I'd use state management instead:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
use tauri::State;

struct Theme {
    theme: Mutex<String>,
}

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
                .manage(Theme { theme: Mutex::new(String::from("default")) })
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![update_theme])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

#[tauri::command]
fn update_theme(new_theme: String, state: State<Theme>) {
        let mut theme = state.theme.lock().unwrap();
        *theme = new_theme;
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding this code correctly? When I invoke `update_theme` on frontend it will update `theme` in the backend. If so, I need the opposite - when value changes in backend I need to send new value to frontend

Comment: @Grayza in this case you'd want to use events. I just updated the answer with the example. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'm interested if there are alternatives to @tauri/apps for the Rust frontend(Leptos). Looks like [listen](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.6.1/tauri/scope/struct.FsScope.html#method.listen) in docs.rs is for backend.

Comment: @Grayza you'd probably have to build it yourself, since it's just a wrapper around `window.__TAURI__.invoke()`. I don't know how leptos compiles to WASM, but from WASM you could probably just call rust `wasm_bindgen::JsCast;` and then the invoke function.

Comment: If this answer helped you, feel free to go ahead and accept it.